# Python wheel package paths

Tags: python, dockerfile, setuptools, setup.py, python-wheel

I'm developing a package called my_package with python wheel. An index.html file gets created during the build, but I have troubles retrieving it.

This is my package structure:

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── my_package
│   │   ├── handlers
│   │   |   ├── docs.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── setup.py
|   ├── Dockerfile
|   ├── Makefile
|   ├── docs
│   |   ├── index.html #gets created during build
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ...
ADD . /vol/app
WORKDIR /vol/app

RUN mkdir -p /vol/app/my_package/docs
RUN make build_docs

RUN pip install .
```

And this is my setup.py file:

```
setup(
   package_data={
      'my_package': ['/vol/app/my_package/docs/index.html'],
   },
   entry_points={
        'console_scripts': (
            'my_package=my_package.main:main',
        ),
    },
)
```

So during Jenkins build I get this in the console:

```
creating my_package-1.99999
creating my_package-1.99999/my_package
creating ../../../../../../../vol
creating ../../../../../../../vol/app
creating ../../../../../../../vol/app/my_package
creating ../../../../../../../vol/app/my_package/docs

...



copying my_package/main.py -> my_package-1.99999/my_package
copying my_package/../../../../../../../../../vol/app/my_package/docs/index.html -> my_package-1.99999/my_package/../../../../../../../../../vol/app/my_package/docs


...
```

And this is how I'm trying to access the index.html file in handlers/docs.py

```
from importlib.util import find_spec

class DocsHandler(Handler):
    ...
    def get(self):
        data = find_spec('my_package').loader.get_data('my_package/docs/index.html')

        self.write(data)
```

But I get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my_package/docs/index.html'
```

Any help with setting the correct paths would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: Why not use an absolute path?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have the index.html file in the my_package directory. But even if I do data = find_spec('my_package').loader.get_data('my_package/../../../../../../../../../vol/app/my_package/docs') I get the same error that the file doesn't exists

Comment: "*I would like to have the index.html file in the my_package directory.*" For this you need to move `docs` into `my_package` , set `package_data={
      'my_package': ['docs/index.html'],
   },` and then build distribution package.

Comment: The problem is that index.html doesn't exist in my local system, but it gets created during build. So if I change it to that nothing gets copied into the package

Comment: `setuptools` don't do magic. The build directory must have the same layout as the installation dir. The last step of your build should be `mv docs /path/to/my_package`